# Copying range of cells from workbooks based on sheetname

Tags: vba, excel

I had received help yesterday on this code, but I'm completely new to VBA so I'm having difficulties. To explain my code:

I am trying to copy a range of cells from one workbook to the same range of cells in another workbook, but the names of the worksheets have to be the same. So the code is supposed to test if the worksheets exist, then it'll find the corresponding worksheets in the two workbooks. If the names are the same, it'll take on the value, but if not, it'll keep going through all the sheets in workbook1 to find the right sheet. The code runs through, but it's not copying the cells.

I assume the issue could stem from the sheetexists line within the first loop. I was told I need to make sure that I check to see if the sheets exist before running the loops, but I'm unsure of how to do that.

Thank you!

```
Function SheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet

     If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
     On Error Resume Next
     Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
     On Error GoTo 0
     SheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing

End Function
Sub foo()

Dim wbk1 As Workbook
Dim wbk2 As Workbook
Dim shtName1 As String
Dim shtName2 As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim p As Integer


Set wkb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\lliao\Documents\Trad Reconciliation.xlsx")
Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\lliao\Documents\TradReconciliation.xlsx")


i = 2
p = 2
shtName2 = wkb2.Sheets(i).Name
shtName1 = wkb1.Sheets(p).Name

For i = 2 To wkb2.Worksheets.Count
    If (SheetExists(shtName2) = True) And (SheetExists(shtName1) = True) Then
        For p = 2 To wkb1.Worksheets.Count
            If shtName2 = shtName1 Then
                wkb2.Sheets(shtName2).Range("D2:G2").Value = wkb1.Sheets(shtName1).Range("D2:G2").Value
            End If
        Next p
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You set `shtName2 = wkb2.Sheets(i).Name` but then never change it again. So it is always looking at one sheet only.

Your `foo` subroutine should be changed to:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim wbk1 As Workbook
    Dim wbk2 As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer

    Set wbk1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\lliao\Documents\Trad Reconciliation.xlsx")
    Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\lliao\Documents\TradReconciliation.xlsx")

    For i = 2 To wbk2.Worksheets.Count
        If SheetExists(wbk2.Worksheets(i).Name, wbk1) Then
            wbk2.Worksheets(i).Range("D2:G2").Value = wbk1.Worksheets(wbk2.Worksheets(i).Name).Range("D2:G2").Value
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

---

It is also a good idea to include `Option Explicit` as the first line of your code module.  I had typos in my answer because I had copy/pasted your original code, but you had defined variables `wbk1` and `wbk2` and then used `wkb1` and `wkb2` instead.  As `wkb1` and `wkb2` weren't explicitly declared, they were implicitly created as `Variant`, which then led to problems in code which expected `Workbook`.

`Option Explicit` instructs the compiler to force you to explicitly declare all variables, thus picking up such typos.

Comment: I see what you're doing. It gives me an ByRef Argument mismatch error with the line:
SheetExists(wkb2.worksheets(i).Name, wkb1), it highlighted wkb1

I did notice that the shtname wasn't changing within that loop. This makes a lot more sense

Comment: Sorry - typos ("wkb" instead of "wbk") - will fix the answer

Comment: @leetontea - I worked out **why** I had typos.  See the comment I added to the end of my answer.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't catch that typo as well... THANK YOU! You helped me so much. Appreciate it